# What type of screws are used for computer fans?

Tags: fan

How are standard computer fan screws called?

Comment: good q, but best thing may be to not use screws. you can get a bag of screwless fasteners . antec used to do something like it years ago. i see some -not from antec - on ebay.

Comment: @barlop I'm aware of advantages and disadvantages of alternative mounting systems, but in this question I do need the screw type.

Comment: http://www.pencomsf.com/mechanical/fan_screws.aspx <<< all the info you need on pc fan screws :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently they're  7/32" /5.5mm self tapping screws, though  some places say they're 3/8". I'd note given their design, you should have some leeway since the screws cut into the plastic, to use different threads or slightly larger screws.

Answer (score 7):

"Plastic thread cutting screws" is the technical name and are not classified other than by diameter and length.

Like wood screws they do not designate a thread per inch like other screws or bolts

I have a small drawer full of them I have salvaged from discarded items, plastic thread cutting screws are handy to have around since most everything is plastic these days.

Comment: Most fans I've seen are braced using metal screws actually, though I have seen some of those plastic ones as-well.

Comment: Some fans don't use screws at all, they use rubber bungee fasteners. Its a broad question.

Answer (score 3):

In most stores and retailers you'll find them exactly under that description.
"PC fan screws", "Case fan screws" etc'.

If this is a more academic question, I'd love, too, know if they have a special type name, but I doubt it.

Comment: I need exact type and "fan screw" doesn't help.

Comment: After doing some research, I do believe that they are from M5.5 series.

Comment: Aside from that description, the measurement of the screw might help (height and diameter), unfortunately I don't have one to measure at the moment, sorry. EDIT: glad you found it and good to know (if indeed it is)

Comment: I can't get good measurement, because I don' have precise instruments, but after taking a look at one screw, I guess that they probably aren't M5 or similar. Length is around 10 mm and diameter is between 2 mm and 3 mm. I'm also looking at some computer fan datasheets and diameter for hole for the one I'm looking at is 2.5 mm.

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong here, but to me they look like euro screws (drawer runner screws).

This listing looks to be the same size as the screw I was comparing to:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/vht/Draw-Runner-Screws-Euro-Flat-head-Countersunk/B00T30LGPQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1483538625&sr=8-1&keywords=euro+screw

And the title of this Alibaba listing seems to agree with me:

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/countersunk-cross-pozi-drive-computer-fan_60585217014.html